# Javascript - generating tables based on JSON data

Tags: javascript

In my web application I want to make a site, which holds several (even hundreds) of html (bootstrap) tables. All these tables will be generated based on the JSON file located somewhere on the server.

I already have a code which fills the table based on the JSON's data:

```
function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].age}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].birthdate}</td>
                      </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }
```

Using jQuery. However, the problem with this is that I don't know how many tables I want to generate (because it depends on the number of objects in json file), so I can't prepare these HTML elements before, I actually run some script. Is there any tool or any way that you would recommend me for doing this? Part of my web app also uses php so in case it would be necessary I can use it as well, but more likely this should easily go with javascript and maybe some of its libraries...

Comment: If your program can read the JSON file it can count the objects.

Comment: `Object.keys(data).length` is the *"length"* and data[i] equivalent would be `data[Object.keys(data)[i]]`

Comment: Yes, but is there any way to actually generate that HTML code based on this length?

Comment: `elemName.appendChild`.. `document.createElement(localname)` `localname` is something like `"div"` or `"script"`

Comment: 1. what does the json look  like. 2. I believe your problem is to know how to dynamically create a table element and add it to the dom. Is that it ?